# Navigating JSON array in PHP not working

Tags: php, arrays, json

So I have this JSON array:

```
$countryCodes = json_decode("{
    "Codes": [
        {"Code":"AD","Country":"Andorra"},
        {"Code":"AE","Country":"United Arab Emirates (الإمارات العربيّة المتّحدة)"},
        {"Code":"AF","Country":"Afghanistan (افغانستان)"},
        {"Code":"AG","Country":"Antigua and Barbuda"},
        {"Code":"AI","Country":"Anguilla"},
        {"Code":"AL","Country":"Albania (Shqipëria)"},
        {"Code":"AM","Country":"Armenia (Հայաստան)"},
        {"Code":"AO","Country":"Angola"},
        {"Code":"AQ","Country":"Antarctica"},
        {"Code":"AR","Country":"Argentina"},
        {"Code":"AS","Country":"American Samoa"},
        {"Code":"AT","Country":"Austria (Österreich)"},
        {"Code":"AU","Country":"Australia"},
        {"Code":"AW","Country":"Aruba"},
        {"Code":"AX","Country":"Aland Islands"},
        {"Code":"AZ","Country":"Azerbaijan (Azərbaycan)"},
        {"Code":"BA","Country":"Bosnia and Herzegovina (Bosna i Hercegovina)"},
        {"Code":"BB","Country":"Barbados"},
        {"Code":"BD","Country":"Bangladesh (বাংলাদেশ)"},
        {"Code":"BE","Country":"Belgium (België)"},
        {"Code":"BF","Country":"Burkina Faso"},
        {"Code":"BG","Country":"Bulgaria (България)"},
        {"Code":"BH","Country":"Bahrain (البحرين)"},
        {"Code":"BI","Country":"Burundi (Uburundi)"},
        {"Code":"BJ","Country":"Benin (Bénin)"},
        {"Code":"BL","Country":"Saint Barthélemy"},
        {"Code":"BM","Country":"Bermuda"},
        {"Code":"BN","Country":"Brunei (Brunei Darussalam)"},
        {"Code":"BO","Country":"Bolivia, Plurinational State of"},
        {"Code":"BQ","Country":"Bonaire, Sint Eustatius and Saba"},
        {"Code":"BR","Country":"Brazil (Brasil)"},
        {"Code":"BS","Country":"Bahamas"},
        {"Code":"BT","Country":"Bhutan (འབྲུག་ཡུལ)"},
        {"Code":"BV","Country":"Bouvet Island"},
        {"Code":"BW","Country":"Botswana"},
        {"Code":"BY","Country":"Belarus (Белару́сь)"},
        {"Code":"BZ","Country":"Belize"},
        {"Code":"CA","Country":"Canada"},
        {"Code":"CC","Country":"Cocos (Keeling) Islands"},
        {"Code":"CD","Country":"Congo, Democratic Republic of the"},
        {"Code":"CF","Country":"Central African Republic (République Centrafricaine)"},
        {"Code":"CG","Country":"Congo"},
        {"Code":"CH","Country":"Switzerland (Schweiz)"},
        {"Code":"CI","Country":"Côte d&#39;Ivoire"},
        {"Code":"CK","Country":"Cook Islands"},
        {"Code":"CL","Country":"Chile"},
        {"Code":"CM","Country":"Cameroon (Cameroun)"},
        {"Code":"CN","Country":"China (中国)"},
        {"Code":"CO","Country":"Colombia"},
        {"Code":"CR","Country":"Costa Rica"},
        {"Code":"CU","Country":"Cuba"},
        {"Code":"CV","Country":"Cape Verde (Cabo Verde)"},
        {"Code":"CW","Country":"Curaçao"},
        {"Code":"CX","Country":"Christmas Island"},
        {"Code":"CY","Country":"Cyprus (Κυπρος)"},
        {"Code":"CZ","Country":"Czech Republic (Česko)"},
        {"Code":"DE","Country":"Germany (Deutschland)"},
        {"Code":"DJ","Country":"Djibouti"},
        {"Code":"DK","Country":"Denmark (Danmark)"},
        {"Code":"DM","Country":"Dominica"},
        {"Code":"DO","Country":"Dominican Republic"},
        {"Code":"DZ","Country":"Algeria (الجزائر)"},
        {"Code":"EC","Country":"Ecuador"},
        {"Code":"EE","Country":"Estonia (Eesti)"},
        {"Code":"EG","Country":"Egypt (مصر)"},
        {"Code":"EH","Country":"Western Sahara (الصحراء الغربية)"},
        {"Code":"ER","Country":"Eritrea (Ertra)"},
        {"Code":"ES","Country":"Spain (España)"},
        {"Code":"ET","Country":"Ethiopia (Ityop&#39;iya)"},
        {"Code":"FI","Country":"Finland (Suomi)"},
        {"Code":"FJ","Country":"Fiji"},
        {"Code":"FK","Country":"Falkland Islands"},
        {"Code":"FM","Country":"Micronesia"},
        {"Code":"FO","Country":"Faroe Islands"},
        {"Code":"FR","Country":"France"},
        {"Code":"GA","Country":"Gabon"},
        {"Code":"GB","Country":"United Kingdom"},
        {"Code":"GD","Country":"Grenada"},
        {"Code":"GE","Country":"Georgia (საქართველო)"},
        {"Code":"GF","Country":"French Guiana"},
        {"Code":"GG","Country":"Guernsey"},
        {"Code":"GH","Country":"Ghana"},
        {"Code":"GI","Country":"Gibraltar"},
        {"Code":"GL","Country":"Greenland"},
        {"Code":"GM","Country":"Gambia"},
        {"Code":"GN","Country":"Guinea (Guinée)"},
        {"Code":"GP","Country":"Guadeloupe"},
        {"Code":"GQ","Country":"Equatorial Guinea (Guinea Ecuatorial)"},
        {"Code":"GR","Country":"Greece (Ελλάς)"},
        {"Code":"GS","Country":"South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands"},
        {"Code":"GT","Country":"Guatemala"},
        {"Code":"GU","Country":"Guam"},
        {"Code":"GW","Country":"Guinea-Bissau (Guiné-Bissau)"},
        {"Code":"GY","Country":"Guyana"},
        {"Code":"HK","Country":"Hong Kong"},
        {"Code":"HM","Country":"Heard Island and McDonald Islands"},
        {"Code":"HN","Country":"Honduras"},
        {"Code":"HR","Country":"Croatia (Hrvatska)"},
        {"Code":"HT","Country":"Haiti (Haïti)"},
        {"Code":"HU","Country":"Hungary (Magyarország)"},
        {"Code":"ID","Country":"Indonesia"},
        {"Code":"IE","Country":"Ireland"},
        {"Code":"IL","Country":"Israel (ישראל)"},
        {"Code":"IM","Country":"Isle of Man"},
        {"Code":"IN","Country":"India"},
        {"Code":"IO","Country":"British Indian Ocean Territory"},
        {"Code":"IQ","Country":"Iraq (العراق)"},
        {"Code":"IR","Country":"Iran, Islamic Republic of (جمهوری اسلامی ایران)"},
        {"Code":"IS","Country":"Iceland (Ísland)"},
        {"Code":"IT","Country":"Italy (Italia)"},
        {"Code":"JE","Country":"Jersey"},
        {"Code":"JM","Country":"Jamaica"},
        {"Code":"JO","Country":"Jordan (الاردن)"},
        {"Code":"JP","Country":"Japan (日本)"},
        {"Code":"KE","Country":"Kenya"},
        {"Code":"KG","Country":"Kyrgyzstan (Кыргызстан)"},
        {"Code":"KH","Country":"Cambodia (Kampuchea)"},
        {"Code":"KI","Country":"Kiribati"},
        {"Code":"KM","Country":"Comoros (Comores)"},
        {"Code":"KN","Country":"Saint Kitts and Nevis"},
        {"Code":"KP","Country":"Korea, (North) Democratic People&rsquo;s Republic of (조선민주주의인민공화국)"},
        {"Code":"KR","Country":"Korea, (South) Republic of (대한민국)"},
        {"Code":"KW","Country":"Kuwait (الكويت)"},
        {"Code":"KY","Country":"Cayman Islands"},
        {"Code":"KZ","Country":"Kazakhstan (Қазақстан)"},
        {"Code":"LA","Country":"Lao People&rsquo;s Democratic Republic (ສາທາລະນະລັດ ປະຊາທິປະໄຕ ປະຊາຊົນລາວ)"},
        {"Code":"LB","Country":"Lebanon (لبنان)"},
        {"Code":"LC","Country":"Saint Lucia"},
        {"Code":"LI","Country":"Liechtenstein"},
        {"Code":"LK","Country":"Sri Lanka"},
        {"Code":"LR","Country":"Liberia"},
        {"Code":"LS","Country":"Lesotho"},
        {"Code":"LT","Country":"Lithuania (Lietuva)"},
        {"Code":"LU","Country":"Luxembourg (Lëtzebuerg)"},
        {"Code":"LV","Country":"Latvia (Latvija)"},
        {"Code":"LY","Country":"Libya (ليبيا)"},
        {"Code":"MA","Country":"Morocco (المغرب)"},
        {"Code":"MC","Country":"Monaco"},
        {"Code":"MD","Country":"Moldova, Republic of"},
        {"Code":"ME","Country":"Montenegro (Црна Гора)"},
        {"Code":"MF","Country":"Saint Martin (French part)"},
        {"Code":"MG","Country":"Madagascar (Madagasikara)"},
        {"Code":"MH","Country":"Marshall Islands"},
        {"Code":"MK","Country":"Macedonia, the former Yugoslav Republic of (Македонија)"},
        {"Code":"ML","Country":"Mali"},
        {"Code":"MM","Country":"Myanmar (Burma)"},
        {"Code":"MN","Country":"Mongolia (Монгол Улс)"},
        {"Code":"MO","Country":"Macao"},
        {"Code":"MP","Country":"Northern Mariana Islands"},
        {"Code":"MQ","Country":"Martinique"},
        {"Code":"MR","Country":"Mauritania (موريتانيا)"},
        {"Code":"MS","Country":"Montserrat"},
        {"Code":"MT","Country":"Malta"},
        {"Code":"MU","Country":"Mauritius"},
        {"Code":"MV","Country":"Maldives"},
        {"Code":"MW","Country":"Malawi"},
        {"Code":"MX","Country":"Mexico (México)"},
        {"Code":"MY","Country":"Malaysia"},
        {"Code":"MZ","Country":"Mozambique (Moçambique)"},
        {"Code":"NA","Country":"Namibia"},
        {"Code":"NC","Country":"New Caledonia"},
        {"Code":"NE","Country":"Niger"},
        {"Code":"NF","Country":"Norfolk Island"},
        {"Code":"NG","Country":"Nigeria"},
        {"Code":"NI","Country":"Nicaragua"},
        {"Code":"NL","Country":"Netherlands (Nederland)"},
        {"Code":"NO","Country":"Norway (Norge)"},
        {"Code":"NP","Country":"Nepal (नेपाल)"},
        {"Code":"NR","Country":"Nauru (Naoero)"},
        {"Code":"NU","Country":"Niue"},
        {"Code":"NZ","Country":"New Zealand"},
        {"Code":"OM","Country":"Oman (عمان)"},
        {"Code":"PA","Country":"Panama (Panamá)"},
        {"Code":"PE","Country":"Peru (Perú)"},
        {"Code":"PF","Country":"French Polynesia"},
        {"Code":"PG","Country":"Papua New Guinea"},
        {"Code":"PH","Country":"Philippines (Pilipinas)"},
        {"Code":"PK","Country":"Pakistan (پاکستان)"},
        {"Code":"PL","Country":"Poland (Polska)"},
        {"Code":"PM","Country":"Saint Pierre and Miquelon"},
        {"Code":"PN","Country":"Pitcairn"},
        {"Code":"PR","Country":"Puerto Rico"},
        {"Code":"PS","Country":"Palestine, State of"},
        {"Code":"PT","Country":"Portugal"},
        {"Code":"PW","Country":"Palau (Belau)"},
        {"Code":"PY","Country":"Paraguay"},
        {"Code":"QA","Country":"Qatar (قطر)"},
        {"Code":"RE","Country":"Réunion"},
        {"Code":"RO","Country":"Romania (România)"},
        {"Code":"RS","Country":"Serbia (Србија)"},
        {"Code":"RU","Country":"Russian Federation (Россия)"},
        {"Code":"RW","Country":"Rwanda"},
        {"Code":"SA","Country":"Saudi Arabia (المملكة العربية السعودية)"},
        {"Code":"SB","Country":"Solomon Islands"},
        {"Code":"SC","Country":"Seychelles"},
        {"Code":"SD","Country":"Sudan (السودان)"},
        {"Code":"SE","Country":"Sweden (Sverige)"},
        {"Code":"SG","Country":"Singapore (Singapura)"},
        {"Code":"SH","Country":"Saint Helena, Ascension and Tristan da Cunha"},
        {"Code":"SI","Country":"Slovenia (Slovenija)"},
        {"Code":"SJ","Country":"Svalbard and Jan Mayen"},
        {"Code":"SK","Country":"Slovakia (Slovensko)"},
        {"Code":"SL","Country":"Sierra Leone"},
        {"Code":"SM","Country":"San Marino"},
        {"Code":"SN","Country":"Senegal (Sénégal)"},
        {"Code":"SO","Country":"Somalia (Soomaaliya)"},
        {"Code":"SR","Country":"Suriname"},
        {"Code":"SS","Country":"South Sudan"},
        {"Code":"ST","Country":"São Tomé and Príncipe"},
        {"Code":"SV","Country":"El Salvador"},
        {"Code":"SX","Country":"Sint Maarten (Dutch part)"},
        {"Code":"SY","Country":"Syrian Arab Republic (سوريا)"},
        {"Code":"SZ","Country":"Swaziland"},
        {"Code":"TC","Country":"Turks and Caicos Islands"},
        {"Code":"TD","Country":"Chad (Tchad)"},
        {"Code":"TF","Country":"French Southern Territories"},
        {"Code":"TG","Country":"Togo"},
        {"Code":"TH","Country":"Thailand (ราชอาณาจักรไทย)"},
        {"Code":"TJ","Country":"Tajikistan (Тоҷикистон)"},
        {"Code":"TK","Country":"Tokelau"},
        {"Code":"TL","Country":"Timor-Leste"},
        {"Code":"TM","Country":"Turkmenistan (Türkmenistan)"},
        {"Code":"TN","Country":"Tunisia (تونس)"},
        {"Code":"TO","Country":"Tonga"},
        {"Code":"TR","Country":"Turkey (Türkiye)"},
        {"Code":"TT","Country":"Trinidad and Tobago"},
        {"Code":"TV","Country":"Tuvalu"},
        {"Code":"TW","Country":"Taiwan, Province of Chine (台灣)"},
        {"Code":"TZ","Country":"Tanzania, United Republic of"},
        {"Code":"UA","Country":"Ukraine (Україна)"},
        {"Code":"UG","Country":"Uganda"},
        {"Code":"UM","Country":"United States minor outlying islands"},
        {"Code":"US","Country":"United States"},
        {"Code":"UY","Country":"Uruguay"},
        {"Code":"UZ","Country":"Uzbekistan (O&lsquo;zbekiston)"},
        {"Code":"VA","Country":"Vatican City (Città del Vaticano)"},
        {"Code":"VC","Country":"Saint Vincent and the Grenadines"},
        {"Code":"VE","Country":"Venezuela, Bolivarian Republic of"},
        {"Code":"VG","Country":"Virgin Islands, British"},
        {"Code":"VI","Country":"Virgin Islands, U.S."},
        {"Code":"VN","Country":"Vietnam (Việt Nam)"},
        {"Code":"VU","Country":"Vanuatu"},
        {"Code":"WF","Country":"Wallis and Futuna"},
        {"Code":"WS","Country":"Samoa"},
        {"Code":"YE","Country":"Yemen (اليمن)"},
        {"Code":"YT","Country":"Mayotte"},
        {"Code":"ZA","Country":"South Africa"},
        {"Code":"ZM","Country":"Zambia"},
        {"Code":"ZW","Country":"Zimbabwe"}
    ]
}");
```

When I try to echo a Country with it's Code, it doesn't work:

```
echo $countryCodes->Codes->Code['AO'];
```

I don't think I understand the proper method to do this, how can I display the Country Name by searching the JSON with the Country Code?

Comment: `Codes` is an array. Use an index `[0]`, or a foreach loop. Try http://array.include-once.org/

Comment: Then it only returns the first country

Answer (score 2):

You have an array so you have to search on the array using a foreach loop then you can check string and print the result

```
foreach($countryCodes->Codes as $Codes)
   if($Codes->Code == "IT")
      echo "Code: ".$Codes->Code." - Country: ".$Codes->Country."\n";
```

If you want you can use break or use a for loop to stop search in the array.

ah, You have to change the first and last " into '

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($countryCodes->Codes as $code)
{
    $i = 0;
    echo $code->Code;
    $i++;
}
```

That is how to print them all out.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up reformatting the JSON data as such:

```
{"AD": {"Country":"Andorra"},"AE": {"Country":"United Arab Emirates (الإمارات العربيّة المتّحدة)"},"AF": {"Country":"Afghanistan (افغانستان)"},"AG": {"Country":"Antigua and Barbuda"},"AI": {"Country":"Anguilla"},"AL": {"Country":"Albania (Shqipëria)"},"AM": {"Country":"Armenia (Հայաստան)"},"AN": {"Country":"Netherlands Antilles"},"AO": {"Country":"Angola"},"AQ": {"Country":"Antarctica"},"AR": {"Country":"Argentina"},"AS": {"Country":"American Samoa"},"AT": {"Country":"Austria (Österreich)"},"AU": {"Country":"Australia"},"AW": {"Country":"Aruba"},"AX": {"Country":"Aland Islands"},"AZ": {"Country":"Azerbaijan (Azərbaycan)"},"BA": {"Country":"Bosnia and Herzegovina (Bosna i Hercegovina)"},"BB": {"Country":"Barbados"},"BD": {"Country":"Bangladesh (বাংলাদেশ)"},"BE": {"Country":"Belgium (België)"},"BF": {"Country":"Burkina Faso"},"BG": {"Country":"Bulgaria (България)"},"BH": {"Country":"Bahrain (البحرين)"},"BI": {"Country":"Burundi (Uburundi)"},"BJ": {"Country":"Benin (Bénin)"},"BM": {"Country":"Bermuda"},"BN": {"Country":"Brunei (Brunei Darussalam)"},"BO": {"Country":"Bolivia"},"BR": {"Country":"Brazil (Brasil)"},"BS": {"Country":"Bahamas"},"BT": {"Country":"Bhutan (འབྲུག་ཡུལ)"},"BV": {"Country":"Bouvet Island"},"BW": {"Country":"Botswana"},"BY": {"Country":"Belarus (Белару́сь)"},"BZ": {"Country":"Belize"},"CA": {"Country":"Canada"},"CC": {"Country":"Cocos Islands"},"CD": {"Country":"Congo, Democratic Republic of the"},"CF": {"Country":"Central African Republic (République Centrafricaine)"},"CG": {"Country":"Congo"},"CH": {"Country":"Switzerland (Schweiz)"},"CI": {"Country":"Côte d&#39;Ivoire"},"CK": {"Country":"Cook Islands"},"CL": {"Country":"Chile"},"CM": {"Country":"Cameroon (Cameroun)"},"CN": {"Country":"China (中国)"},"CO": {"Country":"Colombia"},"CR": {"Country":"Costa Rica"},"CS": {"Country":"Serbia and Montenegro (Србија и Црна Гора)"},"CU": {"Country":"Cuba"},"CV": {"Country":"Cape Verde (Cabo Verde)"},"CX": {"Country":"Christmas Island"},"CY": {"Country":"Cyprus (Κυπρος)"},"CZ": {"Country":"Czech Republic (Česko)"},"DE": {"Country":"Germany (Deutschland)"},"DJ": {"Country":"Djibouti"},"DK": {"Country":"Denmark (Danmark)"},"DM": {"Country":"Dominica"},"DO": {"Country":"Dominican Republic"},"DZ": {"Country":"Algeria (الجزائر)"},"EC": {"Country":"Ecuador"},"EE": {"Country":"Estonia (Eesti)"},"EG": {"Country":"Egypt (مصر)"},"EH": {"Country":"Western Sahara (الصحراء الغربية)"},"ER": {"Country":"Eritrea (Ertra)"},"ES": {"Country":"Spain (España)"},"ET": {"Country":"Ethiopia (Ityop&#39;iya)"},"FI": {"Country":"Finland (Suomi)"},"FJ": {"Country":"Fiji"},"FK": {"Country":"Falkland Islands"},"FM": {"Country":"Micronesia"},"FO": {"Country":"Faroe Islands"},"FR": {"Country":"France"},"GA": {"Country":"Gabon"},"GB": {"Country":"United Kingdom"},"GD": {"Country":"Grenada"},"GE": {"Country":"Georgia (საქართველო)"},"GF": {"Country":"French Guiana"},"GG": {"Country":"Guernsey"},"GH": {"Country":"Ghana"},"GI": {"Country":"Gibraltar"},"GL": {"Country":"Greenland"},"GM": {"Country":"Gambia"},"GN": {"Country":"Guinea (Guinée)"},"GP": {"Country":"Guadeloupe"},"GQ": {"Country":"Equatorial Guinea (Guinea Ecuatorial)"},"GR": {"Country":"Greece (Ελλάς)"},"GS": {"Country":"South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands"},"GT": {"Country":"Guatemala"},"GU": {"Country":"Guam"},"GW": {"Country":"Guinea-Bissau (Guiné-Bissau)"},"GY": {"Country":"Guyana"},"HK": {"Country":"Hong Kong"},"HM": {"Country":"Heard Island and McDonald Islands"},"HN": {"Country":"Honduras"},"HR": {"Country":"Croatia (Hrvatska)"},"HT": {"Country":"Haiti (Haïti)"},"HU": {"Country":"Hungary (Magyarország)"},"ID": {"Country":"Indonesia"},"IE": {"Country":"Ireland"},"IL": {"Country":"Israel (ישראל)"},"IM": {"Country":"Isle of Man"},"IN": {"Country":"India"},"IO": {"Country":"British Indian Ocean Territory"},"IQ": {"Country":"Iraq (العراق)"},"IR": {"Country":"Iran (ایران)"},"IS": {"Country":"Iceland (Ísland)"},"IT": {"Country":"Italy (Italia)"},"JE": {"Country":"Jersey"},"JM": {"Country":"Jamaica"},"JO": {"Country":"Jordan (الاردن)"},"JP": {"Country":"Japan (日本)"},"KE": {"Country":"Kenya"},"KG": {"Country":"Kyrgyzstan (Кыргызстан)"},"KH": {"Country":"Cambodia (Kampuchea)"},"KI": {"Country":"Kiribati"},"KM": {"Country":"Comoros (Comores)"},"KN": {"Country":"Saint Kitts and Nevis"},"KP": {"Country":"North Korea (조선)"},"KR": {"Country":"South Korea (한국)"},"KW": {"Country":"Kuwait (الكويت)"},"KY": {"Country":"Cayman Islands"},"KZ": {"Country":"Kazakhstan (Қазақстан)"},"LA": {"Country":"Laos (ນລາວ)"},"LB": {"Country":"Lebanon (لبنان)"},"LC": {"Country":"Saint Lucia"},"LI": {"Country":"Liechtenstein"},"LK": {"Country":"Sri Lanka"},"LR": {"Country":"Liberia"},"LS": {"Country":"Lesotho"},"LT": {"Country":"Lithuania (Lietuva)"},"LU": {"Country":"Luxembourg (Lëtzebuerg)"},"LV": {"Country":"Latvia (Latvija)"},"LY": {"Country":"Libya (ليبيا)"},"MA": {"Country":"Morocco (المغرب)"},"MC": {"Country":"Monaco"},"MD": {"Country":"Moldova"},"ME": {"Country":"Montenegro (Црна Гора)"},"MG": {"Country":"Madagascar (Madagasikara)"},"MH": {"Country":"Marshall Islands"},"MK": {"Country":"Macedonia (Македонија)"},"ML": {"Country":"Mali"},"MM": {"Country":"Myanmar (Burma)"},"MN": {"Country":"Mongolia (Монгол Улс)"},"MO": {"Country":"Macao"},"MP": {"Country":"Northern Mariana Islands"},"MQ": {"Country":"Martinique"},"MR": {"Country":"Mauritania (موريتانيا)"},"MS": {"Country":"Montserrat"},"MT": {"Country":"Malta"},"MU": {"Country":"Mauritius"},"MV": {"Country":"Maldives (ގުޖޭއްރާ ޔާއްރިހޫމްޖ)"},"MW": {"Country":"Malawi"},"MX": {"Country":"Mexico (México)"},"MY": {"Country":"Malaysia"},"MZ": {"Country":"Mozambique (Moçambique)"},"NA": {"Country":"Namibia"},"NC": {"Country":"New Caledonia"},"NE": {"Country":"Niger"},"NF": {"Country":"Norfolk Island"},"NG": {"Country":"Nigeria"},"NI": {"Country":"Nicaragua"},"NL": {"Country":"Netherlands (Nederland)"},"NO": {"Country":"Norway (Norge)"},"NP": {"Country":"Nepal (नेपाल)"},"NR": {"Country":"Nauru (Naoero)"},"NU": {"Country":"Niue"},"NZ": {"Country":"New Zealand"},"OM": {"Country":"Oman (عمان)"},"PA": {"Country":"Panama (Panamá)"},"PE": {"Country":"Peru (Perú)"},"PF": {"Country":"French Polynesia"},"PG": {"Country":"Papua New Guinea"},"PH": {"Country":"Philippines (Pilipinas)"},"PK": {"Country":"Pakistan (پاکستان)"},"PL": {"Country":"Poland (Polska)"},"PM": {"Country":"Saint Pierre and Miquelon"},"PN": {"Country":"Pitcairn"},"PR": {"Country":"Puerto Rico"},"PS": {"Country":"Palestinian Territories"},"PT": {"Country":"Portugal"},"PW": {"Country":"Palau (Belau)"},"PY": {"Country":"Paraguay"},"QA": {"Country":"Qatar (قطر)"},"RE": {"Country":"Reunion"},"RO": {"Country":"Romania (România)"},"RS": {"Country":"Serbia (Србија)"},"RU": {"Country":"Russia (Россия)"},"RW": {"Country":"Rwanda"},"SA": {"Country":"Saudi Arabia (المملكة العربية السعودية)"},"SB": {"Country":"Solomon Islands"},"SC": {"Country":"Seychelles"},"SD": {"Country":"Sudan (السودان)"},"SE": {"Country":"Sweden (Sverige)"},"SG": {"Country":"Singapore (Singapura)"},"SH": {"Country":"Saint Helena"},"SI": {"Country":"Slovenia (Slovenija)"},"SJ": {"Country":"Svalbard and Jan Mayen"},"SK": {"Country":"Slovakia (Slovensko)"},"SL": {"Country":"Sierra Leone"},"SM": {"Country":"San Marino"},"SN": {"Country":"Senegal (Sénégal)"},"SO": {"Country":"Somalia (Soomaaliya)"},"SR": {"Country":"Suriname"},"ST": {"Country":"São Tomé and Príncipe"},"SV": {"Country":"El Salvador"},"SY": {"Country":"Syria (سوريا)"},"SZ": {"Country":"Swaziland"},"TC": {"Country":"Turks and Caicos Islands"},"TD": {"Country":"Chad (Tchad)"},"TF": {"Country":"French Southern Territories"},"TG": {"Country":"Togo"},"TH": {"Country":"Thailand (ราชอาณาจักรไทย)"},"TJ": {"Country":"Tajikistan (Тоҷикистон)"},"TK": {"Country":"Tokelau"},"TL": {"Country":"Timor-Leste"},"TM": {"Country":"Turkmenistan (Türkmenistan)"},"TN": {"Country":"Tunisia (تونس)"},"TO": {"Country":"Tonga"},"TR": {"Country":"Turkey (Türkiye)"},"TT": {"Country":"Trinidad and Tobago"},"TV": {"Country":"Tuvalu"},"TW": {"Country":"Taiwan (台灣)"},"TZ": {"Country":"Tanzania"},"UA": {"Country":"Ukraine (Україна)"},"UG": {"Country":"Uganda"},"UM": {"Country":"United States minor outlying islands"},"US": {"Country":"United States"},"UY": {"Country":"Uruguay"},"UZ": {"Country":"Uzbekistan (O&#39;zbekiston)"},"VA": {"Country":"Vatican City (Città del Vaticano)"},"VC": {"Country":"Saint Vincent and the Grenadines"},"VE": {"Country":"Venezuela"},"VG": {"Country":"Virgin Islands, British"},"VI": {"Country":"Virgin Islands, U.S."},"VN": {"Country":"Vietnam (Việt Nam)"},"VU": {"Country":"Vanuatu"},"WF": {"Country":"Wallis and Futuna"},"WS": {"Country":"Samoa"},"YE": {"Country":"Yemen (اليمن)"},"YT": {"Country":"Mayotte"},"ZA": {"Country":"South Africa"},"ZM": {"Country":"Zambia"},"ZW": {"Country":"Zimbabwe"}}
```

This works much better.